# How to load mobilenet checkpoints into a ssd-mobilenet

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, checkpoint

Given the mobilenet.ckpt and the ssd-mobilenet frozen_graph.pb: Is there any way to load a pure mobilenet checkpoint into a ssd-mobilenet?

Ie. ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco from:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

and one of the checkpoints from:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md

Comment: They're trained on different image sizes to start. Even if some of the weight matrices match up, you'd want to fine tune with a few training iterations.

Comment: @sjorit did you find a way to solve the problem? If yes, it will be great if you could answer your own question to help the rest of the community. Thanks!